# C++ Console Application prompt "Run as Admin" to run as administrator?

Tags: c++, console

How can i make a C++ Command Application run as admin?

the program im creating needs administrator rights so it would be nice to let the user get the run as admin prompt.
How may i do that?

NOTE: Im not using Visual Studio, im using Code::Blocks 10.05;

-Stian

Comment: You can right-click on the exe, choose the Compatibility tab, and check Run as administrator. Now every time you start the exe, it will run as admin.

Comment: This is a program that people who dont know how to do that can use it, it is ment to be for more people than just me!?

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the shell:

Right Click on the project => **Configuration Properties** => **Linker** => **Manifest File** => **highestAvailable** (/level='highestAvailable')

Comment: Found this answer far more useful; if you've got a fresh console project and want to do it, this is how. If you have a project where you already set things up to have your own manifest, then the other answers work, but by default many VS projects create the manifest for you.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a manifest file to state that the application requires elevation to administrator. It's a normal text document that you can create in Notepad and it's loaded by Windows when the application is executed.

Here's an example of a manifest, for an application called `MyApplication`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="MyApplication"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Then simply name it `MyApplication.exe.manifest` (replacing `MyApplication` with whatever your executable name is) and it'll get loaded by UAC automatically.

You can also embed the manifest in the resource section of your executable, if you name it appropriately.

See this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Add [`requireAdministrator` to your application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Comment: @StianOlsen Use [`mt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591.aspx) to embed the manifest, or just place a `.manifest` with the same name as your `.exe` in the same directory, e.g. `foo.exe` and `foo.exe.manifest`.

Comment: You'll have to create it manually using a text editor. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @ephemient - `mt` is a Visual Studio tool, it isn't included with Windows by default and I'm pretty sure it's only available with VS.

Comment: @Polynomial: `mt` is part of the Windows SDK. Even if it were part of VS, what's the problem? VS is free, you can install it without problem.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - Sure, downloading and installing 2GB+ worth of application just to embed a single manifest file into an application seems a *great idea*, especially when you could just have the manifest file with the executable, or place it in the project's `rc` file, or embed it in the resource manually using a PE editor ;)

Comment: (excuse the sarcasm, I'm ill and a little cranky)

Comment: @Polynomial, it would surprise me if someone were developing a Windows application without the Windows SDK.  The most viable alternative I know of is Mingw, and there it can be done by adding a resource with `windres`.  I don't know what is behind Code::Blocks, though.

Comment: You don't actually *need* to embed the manifest. Just shipping it as a separate file will work if you name it properly, i.e. `name.exe` becomes `name.exe.manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution applies to Visual Studio 2019.

If your like me, and prefer a GUI method, here you go:

1. Navigate to your Solution Explorer window.
2. Right click your project
3. Select Properties
4. Navigate to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> All Options
5. Find UAC Execution Level
6. Set to `requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator)`

Visual steps:

[image: Project Properties Selection Menu]

[image: Project Property Page]

Comment: I understand the body of the question mentions this specific user doesn't use Visual Studio, however, due to the fact that this is one of the first search results for "visual studio C++ run as admin", and that it doesn't mention anywhere in the title about the IDE I believe it's justified to post it here for future search queries.