# how to check if user is admin in windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, sid

I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389%28VS.85%29.aspx) in msdn  to check if user is admin. its working fine on some win7 machine when process is elevated (run as administrator) but I found some machines (some win 2008) where its not working! 
Is this the right way to go about it ??

```
BOOL IsUserAdmin(VOID)
{
  BOOL b;
  SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
  PSID AdministratorsGroup; 
  b = AllocateAndInitializeSid(
    &NtAuthority,
    2,
    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &AdministratorsGroup); 
  if(b) 
  {
    if (!CheckTokenMembership( NULL, AdministratorsGroup, &b)) 
    {
      b = FALSE;
    } 
  FreeSid(AdministratorsGroup); 
  }
  return(b);
}
```

Comment: This is a similar question which may be your answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139480/c-console-application-prompt-run-as-admin-to-run-as-administrator

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful. Be more specific.

Comment: Not really, @Jordi. That question is about asking the OS to run your program as an administrator. This question is about determining whether the program is *already* running as an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IsUserAnAdmin()` that is a wrapper for the call above

Comment: Has limited OS support, [MSDN recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776463(v=vs.85).aspx) `ChecktokenMembership` in favour of this.

Comment: Of course you are right but the above code is MSDN sample and he/she ask for correctness of it, so may be it can be checked using a system supplied API. thanks for the note

Comment: this is not recommended call as per msdn

Comment: This works only up to Windows Vista and the question is about Windows 7