# How to run application as administrator in Qt

Tags: windows, qt

How can I start my Qt application as administrator or get a prompt when admin privilege is needed? I have tried everything in the posts that I could find about it and most of them are a few years old. Nothing has worked and everyone seems to have a different spin on it. I have downloaded the windows SDK to get  mt.exe, created the manifest files, the RC file and every other methods including right click and set the application to start in administrator mode. Nothing has worked. I need it because a task in my program requires administrator privilege. QFile::errorString() says access denied. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: That does not depend on Qt, but on your OS, you should give them administration permission to your executable

Comment: @eyllanesc I did that. It still did not work.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have an antivirus program and I have placed some files on my C drive. I want to be able to delete them. The files will not delete. Access is denied. Deleting single files in other locations works fine.

Comment: Have you tried with: `runas user:<admin-user>  program.exe `

Comment: In command prompt

Comment: @eyllanesc yes it says The system cannot find the file specified. Anyway if you try to run the exe you will get the error about not having the dll files.

Comment: Qt you can get the necessary dlls with the windeployqt application, look at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: When you install qt, you install windowdeployqt

Comment: Then look for the dlls, there are many utilities that do this task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142438/discussion-between-equati0n-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: You can try to add the following linker flag to you pro file: /MANIFESTUAC:level=requireAdministrator. See the [windows documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/bb384691(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967949/how-to-run-application-with-admin-privileges-using-manifest-file-in-visual-studi) for more information.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer to my question. I had found some solutions before, but they were not working. I found the reason why they were not working. The reason was very stupid: It was because the folder that my files were in had a space between the first and second word like (my app) which causes an error about not being able to find the location.It should be (myapp) with no spaces. The error about location not found was only happening when trying to add the adim privileges. Otherwise everything worked fine and there were no errors. So here is the solution and make sure there are no spaces in folder names.

1) Create the rc file :Open notepad and paste the following text inside then 
   save the file as  yourappname.rc  This creates the rc 
   file. Put the file in the folder that has all of your sourcecode and pro 
   file.

```
#include <windows.h>
CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "yourappname.exe.manifest"
```

2) Create the manifest file with notepad, paste the following text, and save it 
   as yourappname.exe.manifest and put it in the same location as above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="2.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86"
  name="yourappname.yourappname" type="win32" />
  <description>A discription of your app</description>
  <dependency />
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
   </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

3) In your pro file put the following text:

```
win32 {
    RC_FILE = yourappname.rc
}
```

That's it. Now your application should start with administrator privileges.

There are similar post that describe this process too. Just make sure there are 
 no spaces in your folder names or it won't work. Also you MUST run qt with 
 administrator privileges for it to work. Right click Qt and run as 
 administrator before trying to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me (add in `your_project.pro`):

```
win32 {
  CONFIG += embed_manifest_exe
  QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS += /MANIFESTUAC:"level='requireAdministrator'"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the require admin prompt to display, I simply added

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /MANIFESTUAC:\"level=\'requireAdministrator\' uiAccess=\'false\'\"
```

to my qmake file. I use this in my projects all the time.

Comment: error: /MANIFESTUAC:level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false': No such file or directory

Comment: for me:
error: /MANIFESTUAC:level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is config at project Run configuration, adding this env variable:

__COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER

then cleanup and rebuild and run again the proj, it will work.