# Can't copy Directory from Windows system even after I give admin to my app

Tags: c++, qt, permissions, qt5

I create an app that takes a copy of a Directory on C drive windows system to another folder when I work with windows system I give my app admin using this way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579543/how-to-run-application-as-administrator-in-qt).
I use this code to copy the folder with all its content.
this function.

```
    void MainWindow::copyPath(QString src, QString dst)
{
    QDir dir(src);
    if (! dir.exists())
        return;

    foreach (QString d, dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot)) {
        QString dst_path = dst + QDir::separator() + d;
        dir.mkpath(dst_path);
        copyPath(src+ QDir::separator() + d, dst_path);
    }

    foreach (QString f, dir.entryList(QDir::Files)) {
        QFile::copy(src + QDir::separator() + f, dst + QDir::separator() + f);
    }
}
```

and in the button

```
copyPath("C:/Windows/System32/spp/store", "D:/copyfolder");
```

when I test on another folder on D drive it worked so what I can do so that I make my qt app copy the folder from the C drive.
when I give it this path `C:/Windows/System32/spp/` it copies only one folder which is `C:/Windows/System32/spp/tokens` and the other folders not copied, when I give it the path `C:/Windows/System32/spp/store`, it can't path this condition

```
QDir dir(src);
    if (! dir.exists())
        return;
```

it can't recognize directory. so please if I can do this in C# for example or any other way no problem please provide any information, as I tried with C# and it did not work too.

Comment: Can you copy the files in Explorer? If not there's probably a lock on one of the files, for example it's open in another application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes i tried to copy it manually it copied with no problem at all

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If it's 32-bit, then its likely that your path-access is masked to [...]\SysWOW64\[...] when accessing [...]\system32\[...].

Comment: yes iam using 32 as i use Mingw it have only 32 in QT

Answer (score 0):

Hokay, @markus has spotted the rabbit so let's work it up into an answer.

64 bit Windows has something called the [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector), which fools 32 bit apps into thinking they are looking at (for example) `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32` when in fact they're not.  Details behind that link.

**However**, you can turn it off.  In terms of raw Win32 calls, you can do:

```
VOID *oldValue;
BOOL ok = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection (&oldValue);
// ...
ok = Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection (oldValue);
```

It's hard to imagine why these calls would ever fail.

There is also:

```
BOOLEAN Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection (BOOLEAN Wow64FsEnableRedirection);
```

which lets you turn it on (for masochists only) or off unconditionally.

There doesn't seem to be a call to find out if redirection is currently enabled.  I guess you can do is to assume that it is enabled on program startup (which it will be) and then track any changes you make yourself.