# Using <cfgmgr32.h> in MFC - Error CR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, configurationmanager, device-instance-id

I am a really newbie programmer, and currently using <cfgmgr32.h>. I noticed several function I called keep on return CR_ACCESS_DENIED error back to me. I am unable to find the solution else where so I decided to came here.

Here is my code (sorry if it is messy):

```
DEVINST pDeviceInstance;
CONFIGRET configRet = 0;
configRet = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&pDeviceInstance, DeviceInstanceIDW, 
    CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_PHANTOM); // CR_SUCCESS

configRet = CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(pDeviceInstance, CM_REENUMERATE_RETRY_INSTALLATION | 
    CM_REENUMERATE_NORMAL); // CR_ACCESS_DENIED

configRet = CM_Setup_DevNode(pDeviceInstance, CM_SETUP_DEVNODE_READY); // CR_ACCESS_DENIED

PNP_VETO_TYPE vetoed;
WCHAR strVetoed;
configRet = CM_Query_And_Remove_SubTreeW(pDeviceInstance, &vetoed, &strVetoed, 
    MAX_PATH, CM_REMOVE_UI_OK); // CR_ACCESS_DENIED
if (configRet != CR_REMOVE_VETOED)
    configRet = CM_Uninstall_DevNode(pDeviceInstance, 0); // CR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

I got my *DeviceInstanceIDW* from calling *SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId*, which I am confident it is not having any issue.

I tried *CM_Locate_DevNodeW* first to get the *DEVINST* and proceed to my stuff. But right after that, I am stuck. 
I noticed in the .h file it comment //NT ONLY, but I didn't managed to figure out what does that means. 
My questions are: 
a) What does the CR_ACCESS_DENIED actually about (as I cannot find any detailed documentation)
b) How should I solve this and make it work? 
c) Is it a bad idea to use this <cfgmgr32.h>? I am actually trying to programmatically unplug and plug an USB COM device. The actual scenario is more complicated, but in simple word, this is what I am attempting to do.

I seeking to know how to make the code works, why it doesn't at first and how is the solution provided solve it. Appreciate any constructive comment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So since I was dealing with the device related stuff, and error return is access denied, I thinking it could be the user right that causing me the trouble.

So I go on and find some way to grant my program administrator right.
Came across [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967949/how-to-run-application-with-admin-privileges-using-manifest-file-in-visual-studi), and it work for me too.

So I guess the access denied thing is really related to the user access right, granting access is able to solve that. (While I still dunno why the error code in the header file comment with //NT ONLY)

Still looking forward to any constructive feedback on using <cfgmgr32.h> though as I am still unaware if any practice required to use this.