# Can you force the user to run your gcc compiled C program as admin?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, permissions

I want to try and make a installer type of program, but I also want to force the installer to be ran as admin, how do I do it?

I think the result icon should look like this

[image: Image of icon with forced admin rights.]

I'm using Mingw64/MSYS2/GCC/Windows/C

**Edit:**

I have been looking into this for a while, and I made my .rc file look like this

```
1 24 "main.manifest"
```

and manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

And compiled my program like this:

```
windres config.rc -O coff config.res && gcc main.c -w -o main.exe config.res
```

But this changed exactly nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run application with Admin privileges using Manifest file in Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967949/how-to-run-application-with-admin-privileges-using-manifest-file-in-visual-studi)

Comment: If dup doesn't work for you exactly, look for how to add a manifest that requests admin privileges.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Tried, I added an edit, hope it helps

Comment: I built a file exactly the way you showed in your edit, and for me it works. Download [Resource Hacker](https://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and check if the correct manifest exists in your file at the end or not. It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wwqn.png). (Or can you upload the file you get from this somewhere and link it so I can check what could be wrong with it?)

Comment: Could you maybe tell if you did anything differently, like anything? Also, I might be now confused, because my user is already in the admin group at the moment, but when I right click, it says "Run" and "Run as admin", I would say it doesn't work for me?

Comment: The admin group is one thing, running a process elevated is another. Even if you are admin, you will have to confirm running it as elevated process, unless you turned off UAC. You will however always see "Run as administrator", even if in this case simply "Open" (or doubleclick) should prompt the same thing due to the manifest. If neither of them prompts anything then you have UAC disabled in your machine and _everything_ runs elevated by default. That shield icon should also appear on the file - if it doesn't, perhaps the Explorer icon cache fooled you, try refreshing the folder view with F5.

Comment: For clarification: "Run as administrator" actually means "Run as elevated process". If a non-admin (as in: not in the administrators group) user would try that, then instead of simply having to click "yes" they'd have to input the credentials of an administrator user. If an executable has this manifest setting, then it will always require elevation, so "Open" and "Run as administrator" would simply do the same thing.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes, I understand that, but I was just thinking it would be logical and a thing I've seen more, that there is the shield icon and when u right click it, the only run option is the "Run as administrator".

But I will try and make a random user with low privilages and try that way.

Comment: If you've correctly included the manifest with `requireAdministrator` set then the application should show a shield on the icon as in your image, at least with UAC enabled. I don't remember if it shows with it disabled or not and don't have a machine configured that way to look at right now.