# How to Run Application as Administrator in the Context of the User

Tags: windows, mdm

I have developed a small application intended to operate with Administrator privileges. However, I encounter challenges when attempting to deploy it using an MDM tool that allows running applications with either "System" or "User" privileges.

Running the application as "System" isn't feasible as it operates under the System user, rather than the actual user context. Conversely, running it as "User" doesn't suffice due to permission mismatches.

What would be the most effective approach to execute the software as an Administrator within the user's context? Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967949/how-to-run-application-with-admin-privileges-using-manifest-file-in-visual-studi