# How to open admin command prompt from c++?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, admin

So i have been looking everywhere on how to do it but there is no answer that fits what i need.

- To run admin command prompt on any account
- To not need an admin password

I want my c++ program to open up the command prompt as administrator so the user can run admin commands (the use of this will not be displayed in this post!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Console Application prompt "Run as Admin" to run as administrator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139480/c-console-application-prompt-run-as-admin-to-run-as-administrator)

Comment: @RandomDavis so how do i actually OPEN the command prompt

Comment: I assume you're referring to the UAC prompt when you say "command prompt". If so, it would open automatically upon launching your application if you follow the steps in that question I linked. If you want to open it while your application is running at some point, it appears that that might not be possible according to the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418791/requesting-administrator-privileges-at-run-time).

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Robᵩ obviously windows

Comment: now i have the UAC and getting admin working. how do i get the command prompt window open from the c++ program?

Comment: open the C++ program as admin: if it is the executable then right-click it and open as administrator, if your are on compiler then close it then open it again as adminitrator

Comment: @ Kid8 - Search for `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess` as ways to exec `cmd.exe`

Comment: @Raindrop7 I've done that already but how do i actually open the command window? do i do system("cmd.exe") or ExecuteShell(SOMETHING) ? i am currently stuck on how to actually open the command window

Comment: `ShellExecute()` is enough in your case

Comment: ITT: nobody seems to know what a command prompt is

Answer (score 1):

If you use system you can use:

```
system("runas /user:<admin-user> \"program.exe\"");
```

Or ShellExecute function:

```
ShellExecute(hwnd, "runas", "program.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

look at [Msdn: Shell Execute function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What is program.exe ?

Comment: `CMD.EXE` probably.