# How can I run a program with administrator permission when a service crashes?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio, permissions

I have a program in C++ which is running as a service. I also have a C# code working as a crash handler and when the C++ code crashes, then the C# code should run.
The problem here is that the C# code contains some functions (e.g. start a service) which I need Administrator permission for them. Otherwise, my crash handler cannot work.

Is there any way that I can assign this permission to this crash handler without interacting with user. Or, shall I get this permission from the user during the installation procedure.

Comment: How do you have it setup to run as a "crash handler"?  You will need permission to install this if you want it to run as admin.

Comment: The program can try to give itself permissions it needs.   That will fail unless the program has been installed by an account with administrative privileges.    That is by design with most modern operating systems, including windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add manifest which will say that this app should run with admin rights:

[C++ Console Application prompt "Run as Admin" to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139480/c-console-application-prompt-run-as-admin-to-run-as-administrator)

Also Windows services can restart automatically if crash

[image]